# Is it possible to see the history of SSL handshakes going out of OWASP ZAP proxy?

Tags: zap

Let's say I perform some request through OWASP ZAP local proxy, and it fails SSL handshake for some reason.

Is there any way to see what SSL certificates zaproxy offered during the handshake, at which url etc?

Comment: With a packet capture, sure

Comment: @schroeder can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1):

The TLSDebug add-on might help you.

https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/tls-debug/

Get it via the marketplace:
[image]

If you're running ZAP on a system where you can do packet capture then you can see the TLS (or SSL if you're still using it .... in 2020 you shouldn't.), behavior and details on both sides of the proxy. You can inspect such interactions with a tool like Wireshark - https://www.wireshark.org/.

Also in most modern browsers you can inspect the TLS/SSL details between the client and proxy (or server when not using a proxy) with fairly simple built-in functionality. Just do a quick web search for your preferred browser and 'TLS connection details' or 'certificate details', etc

Comment: Interesting tool, but not doing what I was asking about. This tool helps to get TLS for any external address, and I'm interested in checking TLS vs my OWASP ZAP proxy.

Answer (score 0):

what Schroeder means in first comment is you may use Wireshark to capture the stream of SSL/TLS to destination IP and examine the SSL/TLS handshake initiated trough OWASP ZAP Proxy. Make sure other source from your machine is not trying to connect to same destination after the capture in Wireshark starts.